# loadMask doesn't get triggered by store load

Tags: extjs, extjs4, store, loadmask

i tried this

```
    var myMask = new Ext.LoadMask({msg:"GOINGGGGGG",target:Ext.getBody(),store:Ext.getStore('Bla.core.ext.store.Client')});

    myMask.bindStore(Ext.getStore('Bla.core.ext.store.Client'));
```

both adding the store in the config, and doing a bindstore.

The end goal is having multiple stores report to 1 loadmask , but i can't even get 1 to work ?

Answer (score 1):

[LoadMask](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.LoadMask) should be only used on components, not elements - Ext.getBody() returns element. To mask elements you must use [Ext.dom.Element.mask](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.dom.Element-method-mask)

Other option would be to create a [Viewport](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.container.Viewport) that takes all browser space and use LoadMask on that. However, if you want multiple stores to use the same mask, you need to bind your store yourself because [bindStore](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.LoadMask-method-bindStore) first unbinds the old store and then binds the new one.

BTW, binding is a simple thing - install listener on the store that shows the mask before the store loads and hides it after data is loaded or the request failed.